# Is it possible to hide the masterLabel from outputting onto the page in Salesforce Mobile?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I created a custom lightning:appHomeTemplate with custom columns and rows. However, the only thing I wanting to do now to finish this, is to not have the Label output into the app page. The Label field is required and leaving it blank only prompts you to fill it in.

I've tried adding css to the style component, shown below, and that doesn't seem to work.

Any way I can hide the entire Label?

```
    THIS .flexipageHeader .slds-page-header .uiBlock .oneAnchorHeader  { display:none!important; }

.THIS  .masterLabel { display : none; visibility : hidden; }
```

[image: Lightning App Builder]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this problem.
You have to insert the following lines in the css file.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 100vw) {
    .oneFlexipage .flexipageHeader { display:none!important; }
    .masterLabel { display : none; visibility : hidden; }
}
```

Comment: Please do not ask follow up questions in an answer. If you wish to seek alternatives, you may post your own question. It may be a good idea to link to this question for reference, if you do so.